# julia package for geocoding

Tags: julia, geocoding

**Background:** I have a list of human readable addresses and want to create a (driving) distance matrix between these locations using some julia package. OpenStreetMapX.jl can create the distance matrix but needs nodes or coordinates as inputs instead of addresses.

**Question:** I did not find a julia package that geocodes addresses to coordinates (like geopy for python). Is there something around (or is there a functionality of OpenStreetMapX to do such a search that I missed)?

Comment: What's stopping you from adding an intermediate step? That is, converting your listen of human readable addressess into nodes/coordinates, and then feeding that converted list into the julia package?

Comment: is there a straightforward way how to do this without leaving julia? this is basically my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now written a function that uses nominatim to determine the coordinates for a list of addresses.

```
using HTTP
using JSON

addressList = ["Mühlenstraße 21, 50321 Brühl","Joseph-Stelzmann Straße, 50931 Köln", "Bonner Straße 84, 50389 Wesseling" ]

#nominatim requires as user agent and will block you otherwise
HTTP.setuseragent!("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0")

function getCoordinates(addressList)
    """
    getCoordinates(addressList::Array{String,1})

    returns a Vector of coordinates in (lat,lon) format as well as a data Array that contains all the data returned by nominatim
    """
    coordinatesList = Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},1}(undef, length(addressList)) # will contain (lat,lon) of addresses in addressList
    data = Array{Any,1}(undef,length(addressList)) # will contain all data nominatim gives for each request
    for (i,address) in enumerate(addressList)
        addressFormatted = join(split(address),"+")
        rawdata = HTTP.get(string("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=",addressFormatted,"&format=json&limit=1"))
        data[i]=JSON.parse(String(rawdata.body))[1]
        coordinatesList[i] = parse(Float64,data[i]["lat"]),parse(Float64,data[i]["lon"])
        sleep(1) #nominatim will block you if you have more than 1 request per second
    end
    return coordinatesList , data
end

coordinates = getCoordinates(addressList)[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [GoogleMaps.jl](https://github.com/yeesian/GoogleMaps.jl) - I used this succesfully a few weeks ago.

Comment: this has the capabilities but as it requires deprecated packages (Requests.jl) it is not ideal. If I get to it I may try to change it from Requests.jl to HTTP.jl instead.